# Among any $2000$ distinct real numbers there are $a,b,c,d$ such that $|(a-b)/(c-d)-1|<10^{-5}$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

> Prove that in any set of $2000$ distinct real numbers there exist two pairs $a > b$ and $c > d$ with $a \neq c$ or $b \neq d$, such that
>   $$\left|\frac{a-b}{c-d} - 1\right| < \frac {1}{100000}\;.$$

I don't even understand how I would approach this proof, let alone complete it.

Comment: The Pigeonhole Principle, I guess?

Comment: Not necessarily. If we choose randomly, it could be that either $a=c$ or $b=d$ and still satify the first condition.

Comment: Right, the 2000 numbers are distinct, but the pairs chosen may not consist of necessarily distinct entries without the extra constraint.

Comment: @RossMillikan Consider, for instance, the set $\{1,2,4,\ldots,2^{2000}\}$. The condition says that two pairs of numbers will be roughly equally spaced. Because of the doubling intervals in this set, then to satisfy the condition we must have $a=c$ to get a fraction close to $1$ such as $\dfrac{2^{20}-2}{2^{20}-1}$.

Comment: @Théophile:  You are right.  I have deleted my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 2013 IMo shortlisted problem,see this official solution:[2013 IMO shortlisted solution](http://173.194.14.51/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=+IMO+Shortlist+2013+solution&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3a%2f%2fwww%2eimo-official%2eorg%2fproblems%2fIMO2013SL%2epdf&ei=ML1aVaDlPIa8uATInICwCw&usg=AFQjCNEPvgPOgNk4_dEwHvc7RWQYqK4IKQ)

> As the solution shows, the numbers $2000$  and
>   $\dfrac{1}{100000}$
>   appearing in the statement of the problem
>   may be replaced by any $n\in N$ and$r>0$ satisfying
>   $$r(1+r)^{\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} -1}>2$$

Answer (score 0):

Possible proof sketch: wlog we have $1999000$ distinct differences in the form $|a-b|$ and we order them. Let $|a_1-b_1|$ be the minimal one and $|c_1-d_1|$ be the maximal one.
If we can't find two consecutive ones for our inequality,
$$|c_1-d_1|\ge |a_1-b_1|\cdot (1+10^{-5})^{1998999} > |a_1-b_1|\cdot 480284911$$ then simply take that pair of $(|c_1-a_1|,|c_1-b_1|)$, $(|d_1-a_1|,|d_1-b_1|)$, which is greater.